# How to exclude a specific match from my regex extraction?

Tags: regex

I have the following regex pattern:

```
(?<error>([0-9a-z])+type=)
```

And the following sample events:

```
auid=3000964000type=DAEMON_START
footype=DAEMON_START
asfasdatype=DAEMON_START
```

I want to exclude `footype` from the extraction so that it matches only the first and last sample events.

I'm aware there's answers here that mention negative lookahead, but I'm not able to make it work.

Could you help me make a regex pattern that works as intended?

Comment: `\b(?!footype=)(?<error>[0-9a-z]+type=)` or `\b(?<error>[0-9a-z]+(?<!\bfoo)type=)`

Comment: Show what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Well I've tried `(?!footype=)(?<error>[0-9a-z]+type=)`, for example. `(?!^footype=$)(?<error>[0-9a-z]+type=)`, `(?<error>(?!^footype=$)[0-9a-z]+type=)`, (?<error>(?!footype=)[0-9a-z]+type=), the aforementioned but with `foo` instead of `footype=`, and many more.

Comment: wiktor-stribiżew's `(?<error>[0-9a-z]+(?<!\bfoo)type=)` did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?<error>[0-9a-z]+(?<!\bfoo)type=)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PHJkFL/1). *Details*:

- `(?<error>` - start of a named capturing group "error":

  - `[0-9a-z]+` - one or more digits or ASCII lowercase letters
  - `(?<!\bfoo)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `foo` preceded with a word boundary immediately to the left of the current location
  - `type=` - a literal `type=` text
- `)` - end of the named group.